# What is a natural way to say 'The rumor proved to be no more than that'?

Tags: expressions, traduction, anglais, choix-de-mot

I got stuck for words when I wanted to say 'The rumor proved to be no more than that' like below.

---

- 'The rumor of his proposing to her  proved to be no more than that.'

Does this make sense in French, 'la rumeur n'était pas plus que ça'?

Answer (score 4):

Not quite. One way to express this idea would be:

> Finalement, la nouvelle qui voulait qu'il l'ait demandée en mariage n’était qu’une rumeur.

Answer (score 4):

It's hard to keep the exact same meaning by translating this sentence,
Instead of *« la rumeur n'était pas plus que ça »*, I would rather say:

> La rumeur s'est avérée n'être rien de plus que cela.

Answer (score 2):

Another suggestion:

> Les rumeurs d'une demande en mariage n'ont pas dépassé ce stade.

or

> La rumeur d'une demande en mariage n'a pas dépassé ce stade.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the somewhat witty and concise quality of the English, what about "La rumeur en était [bel et bien] une." or "La rumeur n’était que ça"?

Answer (score 1):

Let me put in my two penn'orth :

- La rumeur comme quoi il l'avait demandée en mariage était fausse.